# Call a hidden friend function

Tags: c++, friend-function

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct A
{
    friend void foo(A& a) {}
};
struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        A a;
        foo(a); // doesn't compile because "foo" friend function is hidden
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    foo(a); // OK here
}
```

In function `main`, I can easily call friend function `foo` defined inside class `A`.

In function `B::foo` the same code doesn't compile because the friend function `foo` is hidden inside class `B` by its member function.

In there a way to call the original hidden function inside `B`, without renaming `B::foo`? I tried to use `::foo(a);` or `A::foo(a);` but those don't compile neither.

Comment: make `foo(A&)` simply visible to the implementation of `B::foo`?

Comment: *Declare* the friend function in `A`, but *define* (implement) it outside of `A`?

Comment: @prapin Yes there is a way by adding a **declaration** `void foo(A& a)` inside the member function `void B::foo()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288207/12002570).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In there a way to call the original hidden function inside B, **without renaming** `B::foo`?

Yes there is by adding the **declaration** `void foo(A& a)` inside the member function `void B::foo()`as shown below. This also meets your requirement that you don't want to rename `B::foo`.

Basically we're making use of forward declaration here.

```
struct A
{
    friend void foo(A& a) {}
};

struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        A a;
        void foo(A&); //added this declaration
        foo(a); //compiles now
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zEn1WvdGs)

Comment: I had no idea that was possible. Clever! Another solution would be to create a niebloid in global scope.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Yeah, there are always surprises in C++ though this one isn't a big surprise assuming one is familiar with search lookup. You're welcome. This(answer) is fairly straightforward so using a niebloid doesn't seem necessary here though possible.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, `friend void foo(A& a) {}`; does not declare a method of `A`, but says that the top level function `foo` is friend of `A`, meaning that `::foo` can access any private member of `A`. Simply as it is only declared inside `A` namespace, it may be inlined by the compiler, and the symbol `foo` may not exist in the global namespace.

You just have to declare it in the global namespace before using it in B.

Then, inside `B::foo`, you can either qualify it with `::foo` or use `using` to say that inside that bloc `foo` will be `::foo` and not `B::foo`:

```
void foo(A&);
struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        A a;
        ::foo(a); // compiles fine
    }
};
```

or

```
void foo(A&);
struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        using ::foo;
        A a;
        foo(a); // compiles fine too...
    }
};
```